# Xmlstarlet | remove entry with specified value

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I have something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Menu PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD Menu 1.0//EN" "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/menu-spec/1.0/menu.dtd">
<Menu>
  <Menu>
    <Name>Personal</Name>
    <Directory>xfce-personal.directory</Directory>
    <Include>
      <And>
        <Category>Settings</Category>
        <Category>X-XFCE-SettingsDialog</Category>
        <Category>X-XFCE-PersonalSettings</Category>
      </And>
      <Filename>brightness-frontend.desktop</Filename>
      <Filename>xscreensaver-properties.desktop</Filename>
    </Include>
  </Menu>
</Menu>
```

I want remove

```
 <Filename>brightness-frontend.desktop</Filename>
```

Try run xmlstartlet

```
/usr/bin/xmlstarlet ed -d  "//Include[Filename='brightness-frontend.desktop']"  /tmp/1.xml
```

But remove all Include section, with all children. How remove only Filename node with brightness-frontend.desktop value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XPath query `//Include[Filename='...']` will match the `Include` node itself, which includes all children underneath it. Note that `Filename` is a separate XML element, not a property on the `Include` attribute.

Instead, use an XPath query that matches the `Filename` attribute based on its text:

```
//Filename[text()='brightness-frontend.desktop']
```